# How to scrape data off websites that require validation code?

Tags: r, web-scraping

Is it possible to scrape data automatically from websites that require a validation code each time a webpage is accessed? Such as the case when the website shows you a picture of the code and asks you to enter what is shown in the picture. I'm using the rvest package. Is this possible to do?

Comment: These are called captchas, and they are there to stop this kind of access. I assume that if the owners wanted to allow bots they would either remove the captcha or provide an API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is beat CAPTCHAs. That's possible but very hard. This is a spammer's hardest job - to come up with an algorithm smart enough to fill out those fields correctly. It's not something you're supposed to do, the whole point of those validation codes is to prevent access from non-humans.  If you're smart and motivated enough to figure out how to answer those questions programatically, you can probably make more money doing that than whatever you're trying to do :)

Some websites offer a direct API, which is the way you're supposed to interact with their data. But getting past a CAPTCHA by scraping is not an easy deed.